# Is there a way in pandas to do groupby and count without naming a specific column?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way in Pandas to groupby() and count() without naming a specific column? 
So typically in a data frame (df) with Columns A-D I could do

```
df.groupby(["A","B"]).count()
```

which will give me a two rows (C,D) with the count of non-empty (non-Nan) values of C, D where A and B have the same value. That is all nice, but oftentimes I'm just interested how many rows there are with the same A and B combination independent of what C and D are called at the moment and what their values are.

I can also just pick one of the columns and just get one column with the counts

```
df.groupby(["A","B"])["c"].count()
```

But for that I need to ensure that C is always there and is named "C". Sure I could include a dummy column

```
df.assign(dummy=1).groupby(["A","B"])["dummy"].count()
```

but I'm wondering if there is not more strait forward way.

Comment: try: `df.groupby('A').size()`

Comment: `df['A'].value_counts()`

Comment: I see, very good points, however i need to actually aggregate on two columns... I'll adapt the question.

Comment: can you create a small dataframe as example and add expected output too?

Comment: does `df.groupby(['A', 'B']).size()` help?